# JavaScript:statements after return expression will be executed?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I came across:

```
var foo=1;
function bar(){
    foo=10;
    return;
    function foo(){}
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

And the result is 1!

Just don't know why.

As far as my understanding, the first line defined a global variable 'foo' to the window object and the value is 1, then within the bar function assign the foo with 10, since there's no 'var' before foo, so the global variable 'foo' will be assigned with the value 10. Then return, the rest of the function won't be executed.

But it alerts 1.

While remove the function foo definition within the bar function, it will alert 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the mysterious world of javascript hoisting :) Read this article, you will be enlightened: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

As a short answer: to make things work in javascript like this:

```
hello();

function hello() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Javascript first moves all function declarations to the top of your code, so you can call any functions "before" it was defined. I believe the reason why `foo` won't change to 10 if there is the function declaration is because it behaves like `var foo;`. You are defining a function locally, thus when it runs `foo = 10;` you are just overwriting the locally defined `function foo()` with the value `10`.

Comment: thank you, so the foo is made a local variable by the foo function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's returning 1 is because the `foo=10` is inside of the `function bar()`

so the `foo=10` is a local variable and you have to call its function for the foo variable to change

for example if you do this it will alert 10

```
var foo=1;
function bar(){
    foo=10;
    return;
    alert(foo);
}
bar();
```

Comment: okay thanks guy, I got it with the hoisting feature of JavaScript. The function declaration makes the foo as a local variable of the bar function.